# Does instance variable keeping strong reference to static variable create memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Consider the following code:

```
public class Leaky {

    public static LongLive instance = new LongLive();

    static class LongLive {
        public void create() {
        }
    }

    static class Victim {

        final LongLive factory;

        public Victim() {
            /** Hold strong reference to static instance */
            System.out.println("Create new child..");
            factory = instance;
        }

        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("About to get gc-ed?");
            super.finalize();
        }
    }

    static void sleep(int sec) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sec * 1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            final Victim c = new Victim();
            System.gc();
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

From my understanding, any `Victim` object should never got gc-ed because it keeps a strong reference to `instance` object which lives as long as the program run. However, I did see the "About to get gc-ed" printed out. Could anyone help me explain this?

Comment: You have it backwards, an object will never be garbage collected so long as a strong reference to it exists elsewhere. It doesn't matter what the object itself has references to.

Answer (score 2):

`Victim`s get gc-ed because there is no reference pointing to them, so they can be gc-ed safely since nobody will ever be able to use them again (after each iteration you lose the reference to the last `Victim` becuase you assign it to a variable inside the `for` loop.

It doesn't matter what they are pointing at. It matters who's pointing to them.

A typical case of memory leak would be this implementation of stack.

```
public class Stack {
    Object[] st = new Object[100];
    int top;

    public void push(Object o) {
       // Not checking boundaries for simplicity.
       st[top++] = o;
    }

    public Object pop() {
       return st[--top];
    }

}
```

Note that elements that are stored in the array are still there after you pop so unless you set the position to `null` or another element overrides them those elements won't be gc-ed